# HTML5 Web Workers work in Firefox 4, but not in Chrome 12.0.742.122

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome

When I tried to play around with Web Workers feature in HTML5, my firefox works happily but chrome complains that:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'postMessage' of undefined
>   xstartWorkerworker.html:7 (anonymous function)worker.html:1
>   onclickworker.html:2

worker.html

```
<button onclick="xstartWorker()">Start worker</button>
<output id="result"></output>
<script>
function xstartWorker()
{
  worker.postMessage({'cmd': 'startWorker', 'msg': 'Start now!'});
}

var worker = new Worker('worker.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e)
  {
      document.getElementById('result').textContent = e.data;
  }
  , false);
</script>
```

worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e)
{
  var data = e.data;
  switch (data.cmd)
  {
    case 'startWorker':
      self.postMessage('worker thread start now:' + data.msg);
      break;
    default:
      self.postMessage('default');
  }
}
, false);
```

What I can do to make it works in chrome?

BTW, when I tried out the sample at http://playground.html5rocks.com/#inline_workers
and this time chrome works, but firefox complains that

> Error: worker is undefined Source File:
>   http://playground.html5rocks.com/ Line: 39

Comment: Did you post the correct code for worker.js? It looks like you reposted worker.html by mistake.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad. I pasted the worker.js now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to run this on your local machine, not on a webserver. Workers are restricted by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but as the linked Wikipedia page notes,

> The behavior of same-origin checks and related mechanisms is not
>   well-defined in a number of corner cases, such as for protocols that
>   do not have a clearly defined host name or port associated with their
>   URLs (file:, data:, etc.).

Loading a local file, even with a relative URL, is the same as loading a file with the `file:` protocol. So my guess is that the problem is that you're trying to load `worker.js` as a local file - Chrome doesn't like this (for some good security reasons), though you can force the issue by starting Chrome like this: `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`

Alternatively, try serving your script on a local or remote webserver and see if that fixes the problem. (If you have Python installed, you can go to the directory in question and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`, then go to http://localhost:8000/ in your browser).

Comment: I don't suppose you could put a link to those "good security reasons"? I've tried searching online and can't seem to find much. It'd be really nice if we could develop locally using just the filesystem :-/

Comment: I don't have a link, but imagine accidentally running a malicious local web page that could access any file on your system - read it, post it to an arbitrary server, potentially even invoke certain commands. Generally a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 8):

Chrome can use worker locally without the `--allow-file-access-from-files`. The worker needs to be loaded as a blob.

Example:

```
<body>
    <button>Start</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script id="worker_1" type="text/js-worker">
        importScripts(base_url + '/worker_lib2.js');

        function run(event) {
            var msg = event.data;
            this.postMessage({ answer: hello(event.data.name)});
        }

        this.addEventListener('message', run, false);
    </script>

    <script>
        var base_url = window.location.href.replace(/\\/g,'/').replace(/\/[^\/]*$/, '');
        var array = ['var base_url = "' + base_url + '";' + $('#worker_1').html()];
        var blob = new Blob(array, {type: "text/javascript"});

        $('button').click(function() {
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            console.log(url);
            var worker = new Worker(url);
            worker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
                $('#output').html(event.data.answer);
            }, false);
            worker.postMessage({
                name: 'Yannis'
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The file worker_lib2.js :

```
function hello(msg) {
    return 'Hello... ' + msg;
}
```