# "physi.js" causes the error: "Script cannot be accessed from origin 'null'"

Tags: javascript, three.js, physics-engine, physijs

I was trying to play with physi.js library (). I followed all the steps given:

https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/wiki/Basic-Setup

However, I got the error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'file://172.16.159.200/js/physijs_worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.
```

I tried to go deeper, and saw that the problem with the line:

```
this._worker = new Worker( Physijs.scripts.worker || 'physijs_worker.js' );
```

What did cause that issue? The browser is Google Chrome. I checked, the file "physijs_worker.js" appears in the right location.

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21408510/465053), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37718656/465053) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6811398/465053).

Comment: https://benohead.com/cross-domain-cross-browser-web-workers/

Answer (score 4):

Browsers don't allow creating workers from local files because that would be a security issue.

See also this question:

[Why does not Chrome allow Web Workers to be run in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718656/why-does-not-chrome-allow-web-workers-to-be-run-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Deploy your website on a web server. Without the web server I get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the chrome extension 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en

and use the extension to launch your index.html. As now it will be running in localhost, there will be no error

Comment: Sweet. Works like a champ.  Thank you.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work on macOS/ using Brave. The extension installs, but running the app (you can find in through spotlight) launches the app but no windows appear.