# Why does not Chrome allow Web Workers to be run in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-worker

If I try to use web workers through a JavaScript file, Chrome throws an error -

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to create a worker: script at '(path)/worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.

But it allows them if we use directly through the HTML.

The answer on [Chrome can't load web worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408510/chrome-cant-load-web-worker) says Chrome doesn't let you load web workers when running scripts from a local file.

Why doesn't chrome allow web workers to run locally?

Web Workers work completely fine in Firefox, Safari and in Edge

Comment: web workers have been supported by chrome since version 4.00, perhaps share your code? I suspect it's access to `worker.js` that's the problem.

Comment: Are your application running http (http://, https://) or streight from the file system (file://)?

Answer (score 12):

This question was already asked. The workers **should** work in HTML files opened from disk as long as you use **relative path**. However, if chrome implements this correctly has been disputed.

I advise that you try to use relative path in your scripts:

```
new Worker("./scripts/worker.js");
```

If that doesn't work, see this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33432215/607407

Specifically, load worker as a function, then convert the function to string:

```
function worker_function() {
    // all worker code here
}
var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["("+worker_function.toString()+")()"], {type: 'text/javascript'})));
```

Comment: The answer you mentioned says "Chrome doesn't let you load web workers when running scripts from a local file."
This was my actual question. Why can't we use workers locally in Chrome?

Comment: if the worker js file is in the same dir I just need to call it like this correct? `new Worker("worker.js");`

Comment: @InderpartapCheema If you're asking *Why*, then it's off topic, see help center.

Comment: It's on topic and I also am curious about this + the more questions the merrier- I for one am googling this in 2018 and am frustrated by the sheer absence of identical such questions as by now I expect there to be dozens of answers for this kind of thing , each shining their own hint of wisdom on the subject.

Comment: @VasilyHall I understand your curiosity and frustration. But asking "why" did Google Chrome team make decision about a feature is not on topic on stackoverflow: It would be pure speculation - unless one of the decision makers actually weighs in.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe in years ahead some engineers would pop on this thread and anonymously spill the secret.

Comment: On another note, I'm excited to try your solution from another post - about doing a quick internally-external script via Blob object!

Comment: The relative URL didn't work in any of my browsers, but the Blob-way worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
var cblock=`

function workerFunc(e){

    console.info('Hello World!',e.data.msg)
    postMessage({msg:'Complete!'})
}

addEventListener('message',workerFunc)
`    
var a=new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob( [cblock], {type:'text/javascript'} )))    
a.onmessage=function(e){ console.info('My worker called!',e.data.msg) }    
a.onerror=function(e){ console.info( JSON.stringify(e,' ',2) ) }    
a.postMessage({ msg:'Chrome WebWorkers work!' }) 

// Hello World! Chrome WebWorkers work!
// My worker called! Complete!
```