# Why am I keep getting CORS

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-worker

I am trying to create a simple project on android using chatGPT help. According to what it said, I can offload js heavy work into different process, to reduce the UI thread usage. But it seems I keep getting CORS when trying to create new Worker from local worker.js file. I tried the bot's recommendations to give it full url to the local file, or to load it with 'fetch', nothing helps so far.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I know it should work(as I have seen worker works locally same way on another projects). Maybe there's some new settings in recent android versions I need to give any permissions, but chatGPT isn't aware of?
Thanks!

Tried some tips chatGPT gave me but nothing really helped.

Comment: You write: _I keep getting CORS_. What do you mean by that? Do you get a CORS error? If so, what is the error message? Edit your question and add more details.

Comment: The error appears on 3rd screenshot, but added another one to make it clear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["physi.js" causes the error: "Script cannot be accessed from origin 'null'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202529/physi-js-causes-the-error-script-cannot-be-accessed-from-origin-null)

Comment: No, solved it by adding webView.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true).

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding webView.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true)